# JQuery Ajax Firing multiple times from a single request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that fires multiple times but is called once.

```
function getManagers() {
alert('ajax called');
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '/Concessions/Ajax/Concession.asmx/Managers'
}).success(function(data) {
        var options = '<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Manager</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + data[i].ManRef + '">' + data[i].Description + '</option>';
        }
        $('#Manager').html(options);
}).error(function(data) {
    alert('error')
}).complete(function() {
    alert('complete');
});
}
```

The function is called within my **document ready** function and I was hoping for a single call but it appears to call this several times any ideas?

Comment: When and how are you calling your function?

Comment: it seems to get one response for every two calls **according to Firebug** so 4 calls two responses. I am calling this function with the **$(document).ready(function(){});**

Comment: I have confirmed the multiple calls to the function by placing an alert at the start of the function, but there is only the single call at the beginning.

Comment: You are calling `alert('ajax called');` twice, before ajax call and within `success` handler. Maybe this is the reason of confusion.

Comment: @user1113426 thanks for pointing that out doh!! still multiple calls though ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

is there any chance your script is being loaded 'n' number of times, n being the number of ajax requests made.

You can check for this by viewing page source and finding the script. I am pretty sure that the script is being loaded multiple times.